# How to animate n curves in a plot using matplotlib's animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, graph, matplotlib-animation

I have n curves that I want to draw using matplotlib's `animation` (each curve corresponds to a gpx file recorded with a fitness tracker or a smartphone). It works well when using only one track or two tracks. But as soon as I want to adapt it to using n curves, I am lost. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tracks  = {}
xdata   = {}
ydata   = {}

# in my case n_tracks would rather correspond to a couple of 100
n_tracks    = 2
n_waypts    = 100

for ii in range(n_tracks):
    # generate fake data
    lat_pts = np.linspace(10+ii*1,20+ii*1,n_waypts)
    lon_pts = np.linspace(10+ii*1,20+ii*1,n_waypts)

    tracks[str(ii)] = np.array( [lat_pts, lon_pts] )

    xdata[str(ii)]  = []
    ydata[str(ii)]  = []

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot( 1,1,1, aspect='equal', xlim=(0,30), ylim=(0,30) )

plt_tracks  = [ax1.plot([], [], marker=',', linewidth=1)[0] for _ in range(n_tracks)]
plt_lastPos = [ax1.plot([], [], marker='o', linestyle='none')[0] for _ in range(n_tracks)]

def animate(i):
    # x and y values to be plotted
    for jj in range(n_tracks):
        xdata[str(jj)].append( tracks[str(jj)][0,i] )
        ydata[str(jj)].append( tracks[str(jj)][1,i] )

    # update x and y data
    for jj in range(n_tracks):
        plt_tracks[jj].set_data(  xdata[str(jj)][:],  ydata[str(jj)][:] )
        plt_lastPos[jj].set_data( xdata[str(jj)][-1], ydata[str(jj)][-1] )

    return plt_tracks, plt_lastPos

anim    = anim.FuncAnimation( fig, animate, frames=n_waypts, interval=20, blit=True )
plt.show()
```

The dictionary `tracks` contains the tracks, where for each track we have an array with longitude and an array with latitude data. The dictionary `xdata` and `ydata` is used for plotting purposes.

I have two lists with plotting objects, `plt_tracks` and `plt_lastPos`, where the first is used for successively plotting the track and the latter to indicate the latest position.

The error message reads `RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.` So, my mistake seems to be the return statement, but simply adding a `,` at the end does not help here. Any hint on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are supposed to return an iterable of "artists" (that is of things to draw, that is of result of a "plot" call for example.

`plt_tracks` is such an iterable.
`plt_lastPos` also is.

But `(plt_tracks, plt_lastPos)` (with implicit parenthesis here) is a pair of such iterable. So an iterable of iterable of artists

So, simply put all them in a list. Replace

```py
    return plt_tracks, plt_lastPos
```

by

```py
    return plt_tracks + plt_lastPos
```

Comment: probably worth its own question, but how would I add a changing text, corresponding to a third artist here, which I would initiate with `plt_text = ax1.text(10,10,'')` ?

Comment: @Alf. Same way. Initiate, indeed, with `plt_text = ax1.text(10,10,'')`. Then in your `animate` function, update the text with whatever you want. `plt_text.set_text("i="+str(i))` for example. And add `plt_text` to the list of artists `animate` returns. Note that `plt_text` is a single artist, whereas `plt_tracks` and `plt_lastPost` are list of artist. So it would go `return plt_tracks + plt_lastPos + [plt_text]`